# Display Users from Active Directory using LDAP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I would like to retrieve a User List from my Active Directory with LDAP. My Code is so far:

```
$server="ldap://Server";
$dn = "cn=readonly readonly"; 
$basedn="OU=Company,DC=Domain,DC=net";

$filter = "(|(objectClass=user))";
$connectid = @ldap_connect($server);

$binding = @ldap_bind($connectid,$username,$password) or die("Fehler");

$search = @ldap_search($connectid,$basedn,$filter);
$result = ldap_get_entries($connectid,$search);
```

However, If I execute the code on my Mysql-Server I get an error:

```
Warning: ldap_get_entries() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given
```

I am fairly new to PHP and LDAP. I think there is a problem with my filter. Because, when I try..

```
if (!($search=@ldap_search($connectid,$basedn,$filter))) {
     die("Search failed");
```

... I get this error message. Can you please give me some advice? I know, that I dont use $ds at the moment. But I let it in the code for Information purpose. Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: Your filter should not have a pipe in it since you only have one clause.  Your filter should be simply `(objectclass=user)`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. If I var_dump my $search variable I get: bool(false). I think thats the problem, why I can't get any result.

Comment: Do you have an Advice?